# Referring a to generic cursor in an anonymous block in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In a package `pkg_cost_api` the following is defined.

```
TYPE t_ref_generic              IS REF CURSOR;
```

Below is a procedure in the same package.

```
PROCEDURE transfer_costs

(

        p_source_isbn             IN product_header.mhid_part_nbr%TYPE,
        p_dest_isbn               IN product_header.mhid_part_nbr%TYPE,
        p_plant_mfg_flag          IN VARCHAR2,
        p_employee_number         IN product_header.add_by%TYPE,
        p_transfer_results        OUT pkg_cost_api.t_ref_generic
) IS

        v_gen_cost_rec                  t_gen_cost_record := t_gen_cost_record(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        v_result_set                    t_gen_cost_table := t_gen_cost_table();
BEGIN
        -- relevant code
        Loop

                v_gen_cost_rec.initialize();
                v_gen_cost_rec.gen_cost_code := 'some value';
                v_gen_cost_rec.gen_cost_code_desc := 'some value';
                v_gen_cost_rec.amount := 'some value';
                v_result_set.EXTEND;
                v_result_set(v_result_set.COUNT) := v_gen_cost_rec;

        End Loop;

       OPEN p_transfer_results FOR

       SELECT *
               FROM TABLE(CAST(v_result_set AS t_gen_cost_table)) gen_costs;

END;
```

And the type t_gen_cost_record is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_gen_cost_record AS
OBJECT

(

    gen_cost_code      VARCHAR2(30),
    gen_cost_code_desc VARCHAR2(100),
    amount             NUMBER,
    cost_code          VARCHAR2(30),
    acct_category_code VARCHAR2(30),
    category_desc      VARCHAR2(100),
    category_code      VARCHAR2(30),
    oracle_task_code   VARCHAR2(3),
    MEMBER PROCEDURE initialize
);
```

I'm trying to run this below script.

```
DECLARE

    c_transfer_results          pkg_cost_api.t_ref_generic;

    v_finance_source_note       product_note.note%TYPE;
    v_comments                  nopc.comments%TYPE;
    v_dest_comments             nopc.comments%TYPE;

    v_nopc_isbn                 nopc.isbn%TYPE := '0077449835';
    v_move_plant_flag           nopc.move_plant_flag%TYPE;
    v_move_to_isbn              nopc.move_to_isbn%TYPE := '0077364678';

    v_gen_cost_code         VARCHAR2(30);
    v_gen_cost_code_desc    VARCHAR2(100);
    v_amount                NUMBER;


BEGIN

 pkg_cost_api.transfer_costs(

                    p_source_isbn => v_nopc_isbn,
                    p_dest_isbn => v_move_to_isbn,
                    p_plant_mfg_flag => 'PLANT',
                    p_employee_number => '000159457',
                    p_transfer_results => c_transfer_results
                );
            v_dest_comments := Chr(10) || ' Note Date: ' || SYSDATE;
            v_finance_source_note := Chr(10) || ' Note Date: ' || SYSDATE;

            LOOP
            FETCH c_transfer_results INTO v_gen_cost_code, v_gen_cost_code_desc, v_amount;

                EXIT WHEN c_transfer_results%NOTFOUND;

                v_comments := v_comments || CHR(10) || 'Plant Transfer from ' ||  v_nopc_isbn || ' to ' || v_move_to_isbn ||
                            ' Amounts: ' || v_gen_cost_code_desc || ': ' || v_amount || CHR(10);

                v_finance_source_note := v_finance_source_note || CHR(10) || 'Plant Transfer from ' || v_nopc_isbn || ' to ' || v_move_to_isbn ||
                            ' Amounts: ' || v_gen_cost_code_desc || ': ' || v_amount || CHR(10);

                v_dest_comments := v_dest_comments || CHR(10) ||
                            'Plant Transfer to ' || v_move_to_isbn || ' from ' || v_nopc_isbn ||
                            ' Amounts: ' || v_gen_cost_code_desc || ': ' || v_amount || CHR(10);

            END LOOP;

EXCEPTION

  WHEN OTHERS THEN

   RAISE;

END;
```

When I try to run the above standalone script I get the following error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at line 39 06504. 00000 - "PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match"
*Cause: Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match declared return type of a result set variable, or declared types of two Result Set variables do not match.
*Action: Change the program statement or declaration. Verify what query the variable actually refers to during execution.
```

Can please someone tell me what exactly am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you add the full error stack you get; might be useful to see if the exception is coming from your anonymous block or from within the procedure, and either way exactly which line. (I think it's the `fetch into` but please confirm.) What are the data types for the query in your procedure which populates the ref cursor? It sounds like they don't match the local variable types in your block.

Comment: Error report:
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at line 39
06504. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match"
*Cause:    Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match declared
           return type of a result set  variable, or declared types of two Result
           Set variables do not match.
*Action:   Change the program statement or declaration. Verify what query the variable
           actually refers to during execution.

Comment: @AlexPoole Please find the error stack above. Also i have updated the question's description with additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to fetch your ref cursor into three columns, when the query has eight from the object type. I don't think there's any way to fetch into an object directly but you can define a local record type with the same structure as the object:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE l_gen_cost_record IS RECORD
    (
      gen_cost_code      VARCHAR2(30),
      gen_cost_code_desc VARCHAR2(100),
      amount             NUMBER,
      cost_code          VARCHAR2(30),
      acct_category_code VARCHAR2(30),
      category_desc      VARCHAR2(100),
      category_code      VARCHAR2(30),
      oracle_task_code   VARCHAR2(3)
    );

    v_gen_cost_rec              l_gen_cost_record;

    c_transfer_results          pkg_cost_api.t_ref_generic;

...
```

And fetch into that:

```
            LOOP
            FETCH c_transfer_results INTO v_gen_cost_rec;
```

And refer to fields of that record instead of your redundant `v_amount` etc. variables:

```
                v_comments := v_comments || CHR(10)
                        || 'Plant Transfer from ' ||  v_nopc_isbn
                        || ' to ' || v_move_to_isbn
                        || ' Amounts: ' || v_gen_cost_rec.gen_cost_code_desc
                        || ': ' || v_gen_cost_rec.amount || CHR(10);
```

[This SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42852/1) compiles and runs, with some minor hacks to use fixed data types instead of your `%TYPE` variables.

It might be simpler to have the collection as the OUT variable and work with that directly, but it depends where else this is used. If you need both you could have a procedure that populates the collection, and a wrapper procedure that calls that and opens a ref cursor to give you flexibility. (Or a pipelined function, or whatever is appropriate for how you'll consume the results).

As an aside, don't catch the `when others` exception; you're re-raising it, which is something, but you're losing the actual position of the exception which will make it much harder to debug if it breaks. Only catch specific exceptions you need to handle.

Comment: thanks @alexpoole. defining a local type with the same properties are t_ref_gen_record would work but that anonymous block needs to be added as a procedure in another package. so what i did was i initialized the same variables, as in the type, in my script and used the fetch to get the values of the out parameter of transfer_costs into those variables. That worked fine. The reason i used only three variables is because in the transfer_costs procedure the type was initialized and only three variables in it were given the values. I corrected it now. Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a local type with the same properties are `t_ref_gen_record` would work but that anonymous block needs to be added as a procedure in another package. So what I did was I initialized the same variables, as in the type, in my script and used the fetch to get the values of the out parameter of `transfer_costs` into those variables. That worked fine. The reason I used only three variables is because in the `transfer_costs` procedure the type was initialized and only three variables in it were given the values. I corrected it now.